# Read multiple .csv files and assign column headers

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have 70 .csv files at 10GB each, they are all split files from the original file, hence each file after the first has for column names the next row from the last of the first file.

I want to read multiple csv files while assigning the column names of the first file to the next that are read. I have tried `vroom` and `readr` however they give the wrong column length, `data.table::fread` seems to be the only one working however it does not allow the reading of multiple files at once unless within a looping function.

Here is what I have tried for reading multiple files:

```
lapply(files[1:2] ,fread( select=c("family", "species", "occurrenceStatus", "individualCount", "decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude", "eventDate", "year")))
```

but I get this error:

> Error in fread(select = c("family", "species", "occurrenceStatus", "individualCount",  :
> Input is empty or only contains BOM or terminal control characters

Although it works when removing the `select` function, but I wish to only obtain 8/50 columns. Which I can manage afterwards, perhaps within a function but it takes far too much time and memory if I include files >5.

I have also tried:

```
species <- rbindlist(Map(fread, file = files[1:2],
              select = c("family", "species", "occurrenceStatus", "individualCount", "decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude", "eventDate", "year")))
```

Which gives this error:

> Error in rbindlist(Map(fread, file = flt, select = c("family", "species",  :
> Class attribute on column 1 of item 7 does not match with column 1 of item 1.

Because the column names after the first file have different names as mentioned. Any ideas on how to approach this effectively?

Comment: 1st file has correct column names and all the other files has no column names at all? Do you want to read only 1st 8 columns from each file?

Comment: @RonakShah The first has the correct column names, and all the others have for column names the values, so something that can place the column names of those files into the first row, and replace the header with column names from the first file. It's not the first 8 rows, specifically those 8 that I am selecting which are numerically ```select(8, 10, 19, 20, 22, 23, 30, 33)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this -

```
library(data.table)

#define the column names in the data
cols <- c("family", "species", "occurrenceStatus", "individualCount", 
          "decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude", "eventDate", "year")
#define the column numbers
col_num <- c(8, 10, 19, 20, 22, 23, 30, 33)
#Read the 1st file with correct column names
data <- fread(files[1], select = col_num)
#Read all the files from 2nd filename without header and 
#assign them column names using setNames
#combine the data together with rbindlist
result <- rbindlist(lapply(files[-1], function(x) setNames(
            fread(x, select = col_num, header = TRUE), cols)), fill = TRUE)
#Add 1st dataset to rest of them
result <- rbind(data, result)
```

However, I am skeptical if this will work without giving you any memory error if each of the file is as big as 10GB.

Comment: I managed to improve it while working on a smaller subset of two files, it seems to work! Though you probably need to change header to `header = TRUE` instead otherwise the first row will have `col_num` for values

Comment: As for the memory issue, I'll just have to manually filter even further and run them all perhaps 3-5 times in a go.